# How can I add a border to my table, tr, th, and td elements in my styled React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a styled component div that have a table, tr, th, and td elements nested within that div so far I can give the table a border by using > table, but I can't give the rest of the elements like the tr, th, and td elements a border to separate the content making it easier to read. Here is the code I have so far.

the styled component

```
const Skill1 = styled.div`
border: 1px solid black;

> table{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

the jsx

```
<Skill1>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colSpan="1"><img src={critdmg} /></td>
      <td colSpan="10">Self-Modification EX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colSpan="11">
        Increase critical damage for 3 turns.
        <br />
        Increase critical star absorption for 3 truns.
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Level</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <th>8</th>
      <th>9</th>
      <th>10</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>critical damage+</th>
      <td>20%</td>
      <td>23%</td>
      <td>26%</td>
      <td>29%</td>
      <td>32%</td>
      <td>35%</td>
      <td>38%</td>
      <td>41%</td>
      <td>44%</td>
      <td>50%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Star absorption+</th>
      <td>400%</td>
      <td>440%</td>
      <td>480%</td>
      <td>520%</td>
      <td>560%</td>
      <td>600%</td>
      <td>640%</td>
      <td>680%</td>
      <td>720%</td>
      <td>800%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Cooldown Times</th>
      <td colSpan="5">7</td>
      <td colSpan="4">6</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</Skill1>
```

how would I be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add   `> table, table td {` in your styled component, in order for the child tags to have the same border style.

Is [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-forked-ef303) what you are looking for?